# SQL Server Express 2005 SP4 Issues

Tags: sql-server-2005

After applying sp4 to sql server express 2005 and subsequent reboot, the service pack still appears as a needed update in Microsoft Updater.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to SQL Server through Management Studio, what patch level does SQL Server say? If it says 9.0.5000 then it's at Service Pack 4.